# How to replace all NaN values from array within For...of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

If I have the following array

```js
let initialdates = [2019-12-07,2019-12-08, NaN-NaN-NaN]
```

Why does the following not work for my process in removing the NaN....

```js
let initialdates = [2019 - 12 - 07, 2019 - 12 - 08, NaN - NaN - NaN]
for (let [index, dateField] of initialdates.entries()) {
  if (isNaN(dateField)) {
    initialdates[dateField] = "found issue";
  }
}
console.log('the final array is: ' + initialdates);
```

It still prints out...

`the final array is: 2019-12-07,2019-12-02,NaN-NaN-NaN`

Comment: You're probably missing quotes in your array definition. `2019 - 12 - 07` is `2000` which is not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question. You have made a mistake in your code. Instead of modifying value in an index, you're giving the value itself.

```
initialdates[index] = "found issue";
```

And to replace the function with ES6, you can use filter on it.

```
const initialdates = [2019 - 12 - 07,2019-12-8, NaN-NaN-NaN];
const result = initialdates.filter(value => !isNaN(value));

console.log('the final array is: ' + result);
```

which doesn't contain NaN.

Comment: just ```.filter(value=>value)``` and JS will handle that.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi probably he only wants to filter `NaN` values.

Answer (score 2):

```
initialdates[dateField] = "found issue";
```

should be

```
initialdates[index] = "found issue";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the index instead of the value to overwrite the member.

```js
let initialdates = [2019 - 12 - 07, 2019 - 12 - 08, NaN - NaN - NaN]


for (let [index, dateField] of initialdates.entries()) {
  if (isNaN(dateField)) {
    initialdates[index] = "found issue"; // <-- use 'index'
  }
}
console.log('the final array is: ' + initialdates);
```

The way you had it, you were adding a property named `"NaN"` to the array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let initialdates = [2019 - 12 - 07, 2019 - 12 - 08, NaN - NaN - NaN]
initialdates = initialdates.filter(i=>i);
console.log('the final array is: ' + initialdates);
```

If there is minus, yes a simple filter will remove `NaN`. But if they are dashes to separate date parts, you need to make them string.